# How do I scrape a PNG image and save it to my disk properly

Tags: node.js, http, image-processing, web-scraping, axios

I can't figure out how to download and save PNG images properly.

I'll try to get my profile picture from this website as an example, using axios:

```
    const fs = require("fs");
    const axios = require("axios");
    
    axios
       .get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQs8o.png")
       .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data); //returns gibberish V�&ZJ���%rl�D�*=Y�����

          fs.writeFile("./profile.png", res.data, (err) => {
             if (err) console.log(err);
          });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
       });
```

When I write the image to a file and try to open it, it will say an error occurred or that it isn't a PNG file.

When I log the data I receive, it comes out as a bunch of gibberish, with characters like this:

```
'��BNږ��"V�&ZJ���%rl�D�*=Y�������?��w�p��}0���Ｓ�κ���u!p
```

I've tried saving it to the file with each [encoding type](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) in node.js. I've tried using `Buffer.from()` and nothing has worked.

I don't know what I'm missing. The questions I have are: how do I store the image in the right format? Why does it appear as a bunch of gibberish, is there a way to decode it to base64url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "gibberish" is because you're trying to do a `console.log()` on binary data.  That is to be expected.

However, apparently axios is doing something to the data so you're not getting the exact binary data of the image.  There are probably axios settings that can correct that.

It does work fine with the `got()` library like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const got = require("got");
const { pipeline } = require('stream')

const readStream = got.stream("https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQs8o.png")
pipeline(readStream, fs.createWriteStream("./profile.png"), (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Write complete");
    }
});
```

And, if you tell axios, you want a stream, you can do it like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");

// GET request for remote image in node.js
axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQs8o.png",
    responseType: "stream"
}).then(function(response) {
    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./profile.png"))
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. Tried to upvote your answer but I can't since I'm new here :/